# I need to change background color from white/green flashing to white/red flashing after 10 loops

Tags: c#

I have a Visual Studio form that i need to change the background color from white/green flashing after 10 loops to white/red flashing.

```
    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BackColor == Color.LightGreen)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
    }
```

This code works but it only does the first half, i haven't found a way yet to do it otherwise.

Comment: I guess you mean after 10 Ticks of the timer? How would you go about counting how many times a user clicks a button?

Comment: Yes exactly! My first idea was using a integral variable and adding +1 after each tick, thougth i didn't get it to work.

Comment: `i didn't get it to work.`  Show us that code.

Comment: You are on the right track. Make a class field, let's call it "tickcount" and increment it in each tick. You then can check its value to decide if you want red or green.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public int count = 0;

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.count++;

     if(this.count == 10)
     {
             if (this.BackColor == Color.Red)
             {
                    this.BackColor = Color.White;
             }
             else
             {
                    this.BackColor = Color.Red;
             }
     }
     else {
           if (this.BackColor == Color.LightGreen)
           {
                 this.BackColor = Color.White;
           }
           else
           {
                 this.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
           }
           this.count = 0;
     }

}
```

Comment: This is basically a rip-off of @JamezFatout 's answer _and_ it doesn't work as per requirements in the question. How can this be accepted?

Answer (score -2):

use a session variable  (Code not tested... but something like)

```
...
 if (this.BackColor == Color.LightGreen && Session[Click] == 10)
    {
        int count = Session.[Click];
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        Session[Click] = count +1;

    }
...
```